# How to reinstall amplify?

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I installed amplify with `curl -sL https://aws-amplify.github.io/amplify-cli/install | bash && $SHELL`.

Then I tried `amplify configure` from VS code. The command was not found. I tried to reinstall by uninstalling amplify.

Tried to reinstall amplify from VS code terminal with
`npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli`
I get this error.

```
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm ERR! code ENOTEMPTY
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli
npm ERR! dest /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/.cli-mpkUHmII
npm ERR! errno -66
npm ERR! ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rename '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli' -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/.cli-mpkUHmII'
```

how do i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix it, you have to follow what `npm` suggest you, rename the `@aws-amplify/cli` directory (because is not empty).

From command line run this:

```
sudo mv /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/.cli-mpkUHmII
```

And again:

```
npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli
```